# Mapping names in Python

Tags: python, list, mapping, list-comprehension, names

I have been given the following list of dictionaries:

```
names = [
    {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'},
    {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Kennedy'},
    {'first_name': 'Ada', 'last_name': 'Lovelace'}
]
```

Part a was to return an array of full names, which I did as follows:

```
[user['first_name'] +' '+ user['last_name'] for user in names]
```

It returned the following:

```
['Jane Doe', 'John Kennedy', 'Ada Lovelace']
```

Part b is to Now do the same thing above, only return a list of dictionaries, with 'name' being the key. Result should be:
python

```
[{'name':'Jane Doe'},{'name':'John Kennedy'},{'name': 'Ada Lovelace'}]
```

I have tried everything I can think of. From trying to change the key, to changing back to a list and then back to a dictionary. I'm very new at Python and would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Whenever you have a list of dictionaries where each dictionary contains just a single element, consider this, should you just have a single dictionary instead?

Comment: if you must `[{'name':'{} {}'.format(name['first_name'],name['last_name'])} for name in names]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands  thanks for the advice and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will work:

```
result = [{'name': ' '.join((d['first_name'], d['last_name']))} for d in names]
# [{'name': 'Jane Doe'}, {'name': 'John Kennedy'}, {'name': 'Ada Lovelace'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[{'name': '{first_name} {last_name}'.format(**n)} for n in names]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your list comprehension to the following:

```
names = [
    {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe'},
    {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Kennedy'},
    {'first_name': 'Ada', 'last_name': 'Lovelace'}
]

result = [{'name':d['first_name']+' '+ d['last_name']} for d in names]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'name': 'Jane Doe'}, {'name': 'John Kennedy'}, {'name': 'Ada Lovelace'}]
```

Comment: @MatthiasBurger, see the question again: the OP did post the code, it was list comprehension `[user['first_name'] +' '+ user['last_name'] for user in names]`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  thank you! I’ll try it once I get to class.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda d: {'name': ' '.join((d['first_name'], d['last_name']))},names))
```